# Is there a solution for this error I get when I try to create a new ReactJS project in Visual Studio Pro 2022?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: screenshot]

I tried `cd app/path npm start`, but it didn't work. Maybe if there's any other way to create that JavaScript React project, guide me.
I also tried deleting the lock file but it didn't work either.
Note that I'm new new to programming; therefore your help should be a little descriptive.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: One of the things that tripped me up using React and NPM was that folder names are case sensitive. You have to make sure that when you `cd` to a directory that the casing exactly matches the actual casing of the folder names even though Windows is case insensitive. Give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already started it, you can close it and then restart it.
Or power off your computer and then start it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed npm?
you can install it using this command in the project directory:

```
npm install
```

after that, try starting the npm process as you would normally.

If there are other problems with npm, you can try with this command:

```
npm uninstall <name>
```

after that, install npm:

```
npm install
```

Comment: it brought this                                                                                                                                     C:\Windows\System32>npm uninstall
npm ERR! Must provide a package name to remove

Comment: try using `npm uninstall npm` to uninstall npm

Comment: This answer is incorrect and you have written the same answer twice. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Moreover, the issue OP is facing is drastically different from your recommendation. This is rather a comment than an answer.